# What is the function of a Macro?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I never inporme about it , so let me know so are the Macros , and if they fulfill an important function.

Comment: This is not a gaming only term - could've just looked up a dictionary mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the idea of a Macro is to condense specific operations into one button. Here are a few examples of commonly used macros:

> /#showtooltip Raise Ally
>
> /cast [@mouseover,help][@target]Raise Ally
>
> This macro casts Raise Ally Icon Raise Ally on your mouseover target, if they are a friendly player. Otherwise, it casts Raise Ally on your current target.

That's a useful DK macro. Here's another example of how macros can be helpful:

> The following macro will allow you to keybind all 3 of your tier 5 talents to one single button, your currently active talent being used when you use the macro.
>
> /#showtooltip
>
> /use [talent:5/1] Incapacitating Roar
>
> /use [talent:5/2] Ursol’s Vortex
>
> /use [talent:5/3] Mighty Bash

Certain talents will automatically shift for you if you respec (e.g. magebomb). Others won't. This can save you time.

Previously, in certain encounters you might need to perform a complex operation quickly (throwing cores during the Vashj encounter, for example). This is another place macros would come in handy, but it's significantly less common nowadays.

In summary: Depending on your class/spec, macros can be very useful or just a nice quality of life thing. They're not required, but they can be helpful (especially on some repetitive tasks).

Here's some further reading: http://wow.gamepedia.com/Useful_macros (note that some of these macros may not longer be relevant)